# Xperf Summary window messed

Tags: windows, profiling, xperf

I am trying to use Xperf. It worked fine for some time, but suddenly, when I tried to see CPU Sampling Summary table it looks messed like that:

[image]

The Simplefied Summary is ok but misses information.
Any help?

Comment: Note that this question is about xperfview, which is now entirely obsolete. Recent versions of xperf/WPT come with WPA for viewing traces (Windows Performance Analyzer). The orange bar is still there though.

For best results I recommend using UIforETW (it makes xperf/WPT run more smoothly) and reading the documentation here:
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/etw-central/

Answer (score 0):

Well... it seems that what you have to do is click between Line and Process, right above the orange column and drag it right.

If someone will ever need it...

Answer (score 0):

the yellow bar is important. Drag a column on the left side of it to sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

The orange bar is crucial. Everything to the left of the orange bar is used for grouping. Columns to the right of the orange bar are used for data display, and can be used for sorting, but are not used for grouping.

If you want to group by process and then stack then the column order has to be process, stack, orange bar.

But! Don't be constrained to just that grouping. It can be useful to group by thread ID, so enable that column and throw it in there. The Zen of summary tables is knowing how to fearlessly enabled/disable/rearrange columns.

Take a look at these two articles:
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/the-lost-xperf-documentationcpu-sampling/ and 
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/xperf-wait-analysisfinding-idle-time/